# Filtering dates between x & y using ODATA

Tags: c#, .net, odata, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking into the new ASP.NET Web API as a reporting tool.

In SQL I would do this:

```
WHERE order_date 
    BETWEEN to_date ('2003/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
    AND to_date ('2003/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

...how do these type of command translate in the ODATA protocol URL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the [Visual Studio 2012.2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912) update, OData support is back and the following url works for filtering dates:

```
http://host/api/controller?$filter=order_date+gt+datetime'2003-01-01'+and+order_date+lt+datetime'2003-12-31'
```

If you want to include a time, you should specify the dates in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Comment: Hi I am trying to filter Customers whose dob is > 1990 in Odata Using C#. How can I do that? Following is what I have return now,

  Customer = await ODataClient.For<Customer>().Filter(y => y.CustomerNo == CustomerNo && y => y.CustomerDOB > CustomerDOB ).FindEntriesAsync();

Comment: @Pruthviraj: You should open a new question

Comment: @mhu thanks a lot replying, Initially I misunderstood the problem. '>', '>=' and other  comparison operators actually works with date object.

Answer (score 2):

Using the WCF Data Services client API, you would be able to express the date constraints using a LINQ clause, e.g. context.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderDate < DateTime.Now && o.OrderDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)). In the URL that is generated from that LINQ query, you'll see query parameters such as the [$filter option](http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions#FilterSystemQueryOption), e.g. [http://services.odata.org/(S(readwrite))/OData/OData.svc/Products()?$filter=(ReleaseDate lt datetime'2012-06-19T08:16:01.4283521-07:00') and (ReleaseDate gt datetime'2012-06-26T08:16:01.4293524-07:00')](http://services.odata.org/%28S%28readwrite%29%29/OData/OData.svc/Products%28%29?%24filter=%28ReleaseDate%20lt%20datetime%272012-06-19T08:16:01.4283521-07:00%27%29%20and%20%28ReleaseDate%20gt%20datetime%272012-06-26T08:16:01.4293524-07:00%27%29). [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a great way to see what those URLs would look like if you're familiar with LINQ

Comment: (Note that I don't think that type of URL will work on today's Web API OData implementation as I believe they are still working on implementing support for $filter.)

Answer (score 0):

The OData support in ASP.NET Web API is gone and `QueryableAttribute` will not be there for RTM (at least it seems that way at the moment).

Check out this commit: [Removed QueryAttribute and associated query composition feature](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/af11adf6b3c5)

They also added this line as a commit message:

> We plan to provide much better OData support as a separate feature
>   based on the OData library.

Not a complete answer to your question but hope it helps.

Comment: It's only disappearing while they make some modifications (e.g., they are taking a dependency on ODataLib/Microsoft.Data.OData) and ensure that the quality is where it should be for a production release. There is a definite future for Web API + OData.

Comment: @MarkStafford-MSFT thanks for the clarification. Brad also mentioned that it will be an out of band support: https://twitter.com/bradwilson/status/215660980678569984