# Filtering a double-nested collection in odata

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a collection of Projects. Projects can have 0-many Resources. Resources can have 0-many Forecasts. Forecasts have 2 DateTime properties: StartDate and EndDate.

Using an OData query, I need to get all Projects, and for each project I need all ProjectResources, and for each ProjectResource I want only the Forecasts whose StartDate is >= @startDate and EndDate is <= @endDate.

Here's the query I tried:

```
/Projects?$expand=ProjectResources($expand=Forecasts($filter=StartDate gt 2017-01-01 and EndDate lt 2017-03-01))
```

However, when I run this query, I get a `Value cannot be null` error, I'm assuming because when a Project doesn't have Forecasts, StartDate is null because there are no Forecasts.

Any idea how I can achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe dates have to wrapped in ' (single quotes)

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect on the query

Comment: This is only supported in OData V4 ... is the endpoint a V3 endpoint?

Comment: Here's how the filter works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099479/filtering-dates-between-x-y-using-odata ... you can filter the root level set in OData V3 using something like this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912222/nested-filter-on-data-transfer-object-using-odata-wep-api?answertab=active#tab-top ... in that case the $expand would be a separate parameter in the query you can't merge them like this.

Comment: I tried this and am still not having any luck. It is an OData v4 endpoint