# OData - How to query DateTime greater or equal to given value

Tags: c#, datetime, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to query my OData service for a data with a datetime greater or equal to given value. It is not working as expected

I have read the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/datetime-support#filter-datetime

**Assemblies**:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.4.0
- NET Core 3
- EF Core

**Reproduce steps**

I have tried the following query formats:

1. `https://myurl/api/resource?$filter=city eq 'Kigali' and purchaseDateTime gt 2020-01-01T23:59:59.99Z &$orderby=purchaseDateTime desc`  **HTTP 500 - Conversion failed
   when converting date and/or time from character string.**
2. `https://myurl/api/resource?$filter=city eq 'Kigali' and purchaseDateTime gt cast(2020-01-01T23:59:59.99Z,Edm.DateTimeOffset) &$orderby=purchaseDateTime desc`  **returns HTTP 500 - Internal
   Server Error**
3. `https://myurl/api/resource?$filter=city eq 'Kigali' and purchaseDateTime gt datetime'2020-01-01T23:59:59.99Z' &$orderby=purchaseDateTime desc`

On the OData site, this works

https://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Products?$filter=ReleaseDate%20gt%202002-12-30T23:59:59.99Z

**Expected result**

Return the data according to the query in the same way that the the http://services.odata.org responds

**Actual results**

HTTP Bad Request or HTTP 500

[Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/datetime-support#filter-datetime) this should work:

```
GET ~/Customers?$filter=Birthday lt cast(2015-04-01T04:11:31%2B08:00,Edm.DateTimeOffset)
GET ~/Customers?$filter=year(Birthday) eq 2010
```

Other sources of info I have tried:

1. [Filtering dates between x & y using ODATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099479/filtering-dates-between-x-y-using-odata)
2. [ODATA DATE QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196273/odata-date-query)
3. [OData query filter for dateTime range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489458/odata-query-filter-for-datetime-range/24490137)

Comment: Do not use cast.  Use string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");

Comment: It's not .NET, thats an OData query @jdweng

Comment: Could u provide your model?

Comment: Could u get data when access `https://myurl/api/resource`? I tested your queries and it works for me.

Comment: You should post the $metadata section that defines the resource you are querying, also the results of a `?$filter=city eq 'Kigali'&$top=2' That should providse

Comment: You need a string like : string url = "https://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Products?$filter=ReleaseDate%20gt%" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

It turns out that it is related to EF Core and the SQL data type of the column `purchaseDateTime`  that I am querying

The data is stored as SQL Data type: `datetime`

Without being explicit that it should map to SQL Data type `datetime`, EF Core sends it as a SQL Data type `datetime2`

This is the source of the error: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

**The solution**

The model should explicitly specify a Column Type of `datetime`, so that it looks like the following

```
public class Patient
{
    public ulong PatientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="datetime")] //overrides default of "datetime2"
    public DateTime PurchaseDateTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PatientForms> PatientForms { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this! I was getting the same error with a DateTime column. Most of our application does not use oData, and we specify our column types via fluent API instead of annotations like your solution here. But oData does not use the fluent API so only annotations will work.

I actually solved it by changing the datatype in the database, but would never have figured that out if it wasn't for your answer

Comment: Glad it was useful to you

Answer (score 5):

For your first two queries, it works for me.

```
 https://localhost:44339/odata/Patients?$filter=city eq 'Kigali' 
                                and purchaseDateTime gt 2020-01-01T23:59:59.99Z 
                                &$orderby=purchaseDateTime desc
```

[image]

```
 https://localhost:44339/odata/Patients?$filter=City eq 'Kigali' 
                                and PurchaseDateTime gt cast(2020-01-01T23:59:59.99Z,Edm.DateTimeOffset)
                                &$orderby=PurchaseDateTime desc
```

[image]

Here is codes of `model`.

```
public class Patient
{
    public ulong PatientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public DateTime PurchaseDateTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PatientForms> PatientForms { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you Michelle, I ended up finding out that the issue was the EF Core to SQL data type conversion...destination column being a `datetime`. It was sending a type of `datetime2`, leading to the conversion failure